# Using ssh tunnel with Zend does not work, but it works with a MYSQL client

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have a server with a ssh conection on port 2899 to use a mysql server. I make a tunnel between my machine and the server in this way.

```
ssh -p 2899 [ssh_user]@[ssh_server] -L 3306:localhost:3306 -N
```

Then, I enter the password and it gives me the tunnel.

When I go to my mysql client (navicat in this case), I create this connection:

```
server: localhost
port: 3306
user: [local_user]
pass: [local_user_pass]
```

When I connect the tunnel works and I contact with the ssh server, and the schemas are shown and so on.

However when I use these params using Zend, I obtain the error "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044]".

```
 resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
 resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
 resources.db.params.username = "[local_user]"
 resources.db.params.password = "[local_user_pass]"
 resources.db.params.dbname = "[schema_name]"
 resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
 resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
```

Why I can access with my mysql client but not with my Zend application?

Comment: Perhaps try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` - this *should* be the same, but maybe it's resolving to IPv6?

Comment: Tried without success. Sorry.

Comment: @dlopezgonzalez Did you ever solve this?